# Positioning div like a chat on the left side of the page?

Tags: html, css

I'm not a css-smarty, I already tried some codes from the internet and stackoverf but still not helping.

How can I fix a div on the left side of page, image can be found down below.

Image: http://prntscr.com/fbhhdi (I selected position with red lines)

Comment: can u please add a jsfiddle ?

Comment: of what? I dont find it useful since this thing on the center is just a <div> with <img> and <a href> button

Comment: @GmaSa — Of what? (And code should be *in the question* not on a different site).

Comment: there is no problem for me to post code but no one will find it useful, and its also crap becouse its php with html tags in echo so its kinda ugly

Comment: i find it helpful to find how u have structured them :) @Quentin i mean his Code

Comment: Welcome to SO please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  We cannot help you if you do not provide any code - see how to create a [MCVE] - you can get html by rendering the page and then viewing source

Comment: There you go, this is my code - https://jsfiddle.net/ovtqf0wh/
As I said, you wont find it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the red outline in your screenshot is, for an example, a div with class="fix-this", then your css would be like this:

```
.fix-this {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
}
```

Position fixed will position your div relatively to the viewport. 
Left: 0 will place it to the left.

Now, if you also want it to go full height, you can add:

```
.fix-this {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: This is how it looks now, btw I added red border to div css -
 http://prntscr.com/fbhsfk 
Is there a way to put it under my white <hr> after my menu?

Comment: add any value in-front of `top: ---`. I hope it will help.

Comment: Whatever I add ,it same, except for the value 15, than it looks like this  -
 http://prntscr.com/fbhvm0

Comment: Below `<hr/>` tag, use bootstrap column instead of fixing a div to right.

Comment: use value in `pixels`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will solve your problem.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.leftCol {
  border: 2px solid red;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  min-height: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 250px;
}

.rightCol {
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  min-height: 400px;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 254px)
}
```

```html
<hr></hr>

<div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
<div class="leftCol">
  Content Here
</div>
<div class="rightCol">
  Content Here
</div>
</div>
```